# Generic needing to be explicitly stated but I want it to be inferred

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript problem I'd like some help with.

```js
type EventList<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (evt: T[K]) => void
}

export class EventWrapper<T extends EmptyEventHandlerMap> {
    constructor(public emitter: CustomEventDispatcher<T>) {}

    register(map: Partial<EventList<T>>) {
        Object.entries(map).forEach(([name, handler]) => {
            this.emitter.addEventListener(name, handler)
        })
    }
}
```

Please note that CustomEventDispatcher is a class that takes `<T extends EmptyEventHandlerMap>`.

In the above, `T extends EmptyEventHandlerMap`, and the idea is that I want the handler map to be inferred by whatever CustomEventDispatcher is passed in the constructor. For example:

```js
const eventWrapper = new EventWrapper<SelectionLogicEventMap>(this.#selectionLogic)
        
eventWrapper.register({
  "dragend": ({detail}) => {
    ... // detail is properly inferred
  },
  // I get intellisense here according to SelectionLogicEventMap
})
```

In the above, this.#selectionLogic is defined already as `CustomEventHandler<SelectionLogicEventMap>`.

But this isn't really how I want it to work. I want the event map (in this case SelectionLogicEventMap) to be figured out without me having to explicitly state it.

```js
const eventWrapper = new EventWrapper(this.#selectionLogic)
   
eventWrapper.register({
  "dragend": ({detail}) => {
    ... // detail is not inferred
  },
  // I don't get intellisense here, it still is assuming
  // it's an "EmptyEventHandlerMap" and not inferring based
  // on the emitter that was passed in the constructor
})
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  Right now [I see](https://tsplay.dev/NaDBBw) lots of errors that are unrelated to your problem and make it difficult to proceed.